# Javascript: Converting Date or divide through 1

Tags: javascript, date

can someone explain me what is Javascript doing there?

Why I have to divide the ms through 1 to convert the date?

```
d1=new Date(board.resultsbox.value/1);
d2=new Date(board.resultsbox.value);
board.resultsbox1.value=d1; //Fri Nov 01 2013 00:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
board.resultsbox2.value=d2; //Invalid Date
```

Thanks and have a nice weekend.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>calculator based on javascript.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="board" id="board">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox" value="1383262200000">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox1">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox2">
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="
    d1=new Date(board.resultsbox.value/1);
    d2=new Date(board.resultsbox.value);
    board.resultsbox1.value=d1;
    board.resultsbox2.value=d2;" style="height: 80px;" value="=">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When dividing a string `board.resultsbox.value` by one, JS attempts to convert string to a number.  `Date` expects a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike what one may think, **the casting is not the issue** here but the **format** is.

`board.resultsbox.value` is a `String`

This is acceptable because new [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has the following valid sets of arguments:

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

But evidently, `board.resultsbox.value` is a String representing a numerical timestamp. `new Date(dateString)` fails because it accepts Strings parsable by [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (example `'01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'`) while needs numerical timestamps to be passed as `Number`.

The division is one implicit way to cast the `String` to `Number`. Therefore the correct format and argument set are met and `new Date()` works.

Answer (score 1):

Because `board.resultsbox.value` is a String value. When you add mathematical operation (in this case dividing by 1), it is automatically converted to a numeric value which is acceptable by `Date` constructor.
Same (but cleaner) could be achieved using `parseInt` function like:

```
var millis = parseInt(board.resultsbox.value);
```

You can read more about `Date` constructor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax).

Also, there are plenty of information about how to convert String to number, like for example this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

This divide by one is one of the ways (actually strange one) to convert string into number.
I assume that your value is coming as a string, and to be parsed as a date seed it needs to be a number

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by a textfield is a string, the constructor where you can pass a value to `new Date` expects a number.

There are a few of ways to convert a string to a number in javascipt, some of which are:

- `parseInt`
- `+"1234"`
- `"1234"/1`

It seems the author of this code went for the latter example

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it to number then convert it to date:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>calculator based on javascript.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="board" id="board">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox" value="1383262200000">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox1">
    <input type="input" id="resultsbox2">
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="
    d1=new Date(board.resultsbox.value/1);
    d2=new Date(parseFloat(board.resultsbox.value));
    board.resultsbox1.value=d1;
    board.resultsbox2.value=d2;" style="height: 80px;" value="=">
</body>
</html>
```